# VBA -- variable in .formula

Tags: vba, excel, variables, formula

is there a more elegant (simpler) way to put a variable in .formula? I don't want to use .formulaR1C1

I have this code:

```
Range("C8").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
PosR = ActiveCell.Row
KonR = PosR - 2
Range("N" & PosR).Select
aAddress = Range("$N$9").Address & ":" & Range("$N$" & KonR).Address
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & aAddress & ")"
```

Obviously I want to put `=SUM($N$9:$N$101)` (101 is the last cell minus 2) into that cell and this code does the job. But I just want to be sure that this is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to skip all that selecting and those variables

```
PosR = Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row
Range("N" & PosR).Formula = "=SUM($N$9:$N$" & PosR - 2 & ")"
```

Edit: to be more explicit, the *easiest* way is to use `FormulaR1C1` but you said you didn't want to, so...

Comment: beat me to it by 37 seconds :)

Comment: We should mention that `Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row` will not *always* find the last used row, what I think he really wants, because he said "*101 is the last cell minus 2*". Therefore `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` would be better.

Comment: @Peh that may or may not be true, but I reckon it would just distract from the actual question anyway, so I ignored it. :) Also, `End(xlUp)` has its own issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below (without using `Select` and `ActiveCell`:

```
PosR = Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row
KonR = PosR - 2

Range("N" & PosR).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("$N$9").Address & ":" & Range("$N$" & KonR).Address & ")"
```

**Or**, the much simplier version:

```
Range("N" & PosR).Formula = "=SUM($N$9:$N$" & KonR & ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be trying to [avoid using `Select` in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). You've made the actual inclusion of a variable in the `.Formula` about a simple as it gets, but your whole code could be simplified:

```
PosR = Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row
Range("N" & PosR).Formula = "=SUM($N$9:$N$" & PosR - 2 & ")"
```

Really you should be *fully qualifying* your ranges too, like so

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    PosR = .Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row
    .Range("N" & PosR).Formula = "=SUM($N$9:$N$" & PosR - 2 & ")"
End With
```

And if you have blank cells in column C then your use of `xlDown` will fail to find the last cell. You may want to look at [ways of finding the last cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) or simply use

```
' Again, preferably fully qualified
Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("$N$9").Address` gives exactly `"$N$9"`.

`Range("N9").Address` gives the same. Thus, it is a bit overwork. Check out the first two debug.print in the sample below.

Thus, once you calculate the last row and assign value to it `lngLast`, it is possible to get the formula like this:
`"=SUM(N9:N" & lngLast & ")"`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strA        As String
    Dim lngLast     As Long

    strA = Range("$N$9").Address
    Debug.Print strA = "$N$9"

    strA = Range("N9").Address
    Debug.Print strA = "$N$9"

    lngLast = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(N9:N" & lngLast & ")"

End Sub
```

`Good morning, everyone` :)