# Excel VBA Variable in Formula

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I know there are a ton of questions like this one, but I can't seem to get this working right...

I have an inputbox to define the variable "spiffmonth" and I'm trying to use it in a formula like so:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[2]C[7],RepNameKey!C:C[1],2,FALSE)" & spiffmonth
```

I have spiffmonth declared as string.

Can someone please help me out here? I'm banging my head against the wall.

Comment: What should the actual value of spiffmonth be?

Comment: it's an inputbox, it'll be along the format "July 2018"

Comment: You need to have the `&` in the "'s of the first formula as your saying `vlookup(x,y,z)string` rather than `vlookup(x,y,z) & string`

Comment: Include `&` in your actual formula - `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[2]C[7],RepNameKey!C:C[1],2,FALSE) & " & spiffmonth`

Comment: nagarajannd, your code produces Error 1004

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[2]C[7],RepNameKey!C:C[1],2,FALSE) & """ & spiffmonth & """"`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you Nagarajannd!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA -- variable in .formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321109/vba-variable-in-formula)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321109/vba-variable-in-formula